# "She" and "they" in West Germanic languages

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, pronouns

In English, the third person singular feminine subject pronoun (*she*) and the third person plural subject pronoun (*they*) are phonetically different. However, they are phonetically the same in some West Germanic languages. For example,

- German: *sie* ("she"), *sie* ("they")
- Luxembourgish: *si* ("she"), *si* ("they")
- Low German: *se* ("she"), *se* ("they")
- Dutch: *zij* ("she"), *zij* ("they")

Is this merely a coincidental result of sound changes in each of the above languages? What is the reason behind this phenomenon?

Comment: English "they" is a borrowing from North Germanic and not the inherited pronoun from Anglo-Saxon.

Comment: In Old English, the accusatives ‘her’ and ‘them’ were the same (_hīe_), but the nominatives were separate (_hēo_ and _hīe_, respectively).

Comment: @Janus -- It is not clear than *ēo* is distinct from *īe* .  They coexist as variant spellings of many words, e.g.,  héoran = híeran.

Comment: @BertBarrois My OE is highly rusty so I may be wrong, but unless I’m misremembering, this is one of the cases where they _don’t_ coexist, where _hēo_ is very rare for ‘they’, but very common for ‘she’, and vice versa with _hīe_. I’m thinking back to OE lessons nearly a decade ago, but I seem to recall the pronouns being some of the main indicators that, although there was not much neatness to their spelling, the two diphthongs must still have been mostly distinct.

Comment: This question shows lack of research. You can start with wiktionary, and several language specific websites (e.g. dwds.de). If that doesn't help, at least sum up your findings. ;uxemburgish is a minority variant and, I guess, not really relevant. MLG and Dutch are attested rather late. English, German and Dutch are the main branches surmised as West-Germanic. It might be notable that German (though not necessarily high german) can use *die* in indirect, definite terms as well as indefinite *eine-* "one" or *welche* "some", though not apellative, probably reflecting the \*so, \*to distinction.

Comment: The question is ill-posed. It is not about phonology, but about polysemy inasmuch as one of either forms is likely to have originated the other (probably due to pragmatic reasons).

Comment: According to the OED, "The superficial resemblance of _she_ to forms with initial _s-_ as feminine third-person singular nominative personal pronoun in other Germanic languages (e.g. Old Dutch _sie_, Old Saxon _siu_, Old High German _siu_, _sī_, Gothic _si_…) is probably entirely coincidental." And English _they_ comes from a borrowing. So English is unlikely to be much help here.

Comment: Casting the West Germanic net wider: Yiddish distinguishes; Afrikaans has a non-cognate distinction; West Frisian variants do not; East Frisian mostly does; North Frisian does. Old High German and Old English do; Old Low German also does; Middle High German, Middle Low German and Middle Dutch do not distinguish.

Comment: @Nico Why do you think one is likely to have arisen from the other? There is no reason to think so, a priori. Pronouns often influence each other, and they sometimes oust each other, but this would be a very odd ousting. If your hypothesis is that one arose from the other, you’d need arguments to support that – and that’s precisely what the question is asking for: an explanation for the similarity, whether it’s the result of sound change, analogy or something else entirely.

Comment: God forsake someone is recommending wiki in a science site. There are etymology sites out there for Germanic, it is just harder to find. But harder often means better.

Answer (score 2):

The evidence seems to point to a simple phonological merger.

Looking at the various points of data across Germanic, the /s/ in the feminine 3rd person singular is quite old (vs front vowels in the masculine & neuter), [attested in 4th century Gothic](http://www.wulfila.be/gothic/browse/token/?ID=T19078). However, there is also some influence from the demonstrative pronoun **hiz* in the pronominal system, where English and Frisian gain their singular 3rd person pronouns (with English *she* being a further development of *hio/heo/hoo*, as alluded to in the comments above - see the [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/177685)). Dutch was also strongly influenced by **hiz* in the singular too.

The /h ~ s/ across all genders of the 3rd person plural is a feature of West Germanic, deriving from the demonstrative pronoun **hiz*. So the distinction between the feminine singular and any of the plural 3rd person pronouns, at least by 1000CE, was going to be in the vowels.

In [Howe (1996)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VWsiAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA92), it states that in such cases:

> vocalic (and sometimes also consonantal) differences were reduced or lost, particularly in accented forms, resulting in homonymy but *only in some* in ambiguity and subsequent change.

The German and Dutch examples are illustrated with differentiation in the verb conjugation: *sie macht* vs *sie machen* adequately captures the distinction in person in the verb inflection. Other languages simply changed the pronoun; e.g. English's borrowing of *they* from Scandinavian. This is a clear distinction between Dutch and Afrikaans for *she is* vs *they are*:

> Afrikaans: *sy is*; *hulle is*
>
> Dutch: *zij is*; *zij zijn*

If we go through the merging languages:

- This phonological merger between "she" and "they" happened between Old **High German** [sg. *siu/sī/si* (F) vs pl.: *sie* (M), *siu* (N), *sio* (F)] and Middle High German (*sie*), so about 1000 CE.

  - Interestingly enough, (Eastern) **Yiddish** *does* distinguish the two pronouns [sg. *זי zi* (F) vs pl. *זיי zey*], although it is generally held to be descended from Middle High German - whether this is an innovation or a retention is hard to say.
- From [Old Saxon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VWsiAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA84) (sg.: *siu* (F) vs pl. *sia*) to Middle **Low German**, dated to about 1100, the merger to [one of](http://www.chlg.ac.uk/grammar.html#gendered) *sê, si(e), sû* is fairly complete, resulting in [modern Plattdeutsch](https://plattmakers.de/en/27/se) *se*.
- We see the distinction is weak in Old **Dutch** ([sg.](http://gtb.inl.nl/iWDB/search?wdb=ONW&actie=article&id=ID3962) *se*/*si*/*sie*/*siu* (F)) and has already disappeared by Middle Dutch (about 1100).
- Old **Frisian** had *hio/hiu* vs *hia*, which [merged into](http://www.taalportaal.org/taalportaal/topic/pid/topic-13998813311277191) modern West Frisian *hja*, with a borrowing of *sy/se* from Dutch for *both* feminine sg. and the plural form, strengthened perhaps by analogy.

So it seems the lack of distinction in the vowels plus the low functional load of the pronoun in front of the verb, which had a robust distinction, led to the complete merger of the pronouns, which took place rather gradually over the first few centuries of the second millennium CE.

Comment: Two comments on Yiddish: 1. it is not descended from MHG, but from ENHG; 2. Beider ("Origins of Yiddish Dialects") maintains that _zey_ is an internal innovation of Eastern Yiddish.

Answer (score -2):

Equiped with nothing but wiktionary (wikt.), this is impossible to answer succinctly, and that might be because answering correctly is difficult. If the first few etymologies to try are sadly incomplete, we might assume the problem is contested.

Within wiktionary, the problem can be approached from different angles, that lead to inconsistent answers.

I start with a modern word, its given reconstructions, the evident predecessors and the linked cognates, one language after another. Then I will try to sketch a wanting reconstruction of the development from the bottom up.

a) German 3rd p. sg. f. [sie] "she" in wikt. links a backprojected West-Germanic "*si" ("she, it"), alternative "*si(j)u", promissing Proto-Germanic *si without further explanation; Old High German "siu" is given as evidence as well as cognates as there are Gothic "si", Old English "seo" ("that one (f.)"); no own entry for *siu* of OHG is indexed

German 3rd p. pl. [sie] "they" in wikt is giving no reconstruction, only OHG forms that are inflected for case--as there are f., m. and n. respectively: "sio", "sie", "siu", thus not coinciding in the feminine genus with the singular, for OHG, rather in the neutral singular.

c) English [she] links PGem "*hijo" ("this, this one" f.), that is *hiz (m.)--reflected in " Middle English *sche, hye* (“she”), from earlier *scho, hyo, ȝho* (“she”), a phonetic development of Old English *hēo, hīo* (“she”), ...", therefore the phonologic explanation is sought in "palatization", relation to *seo* ("that one") deemed unlikely; cognates for example are given with Scottish *sche, scho*, West-Frisian *hju*, English *he*, and more, to conclude, ultimately: "*ȝho* is the immediate parent form of Middle English *scho and sche.*"

Already we can see the noted difference between these etymologies. The phonetic explanation for "she" is slightly irregular. I don't want to spell out what it would mean for the development of *hit (it). It requires shift of stress without apparent motivation ("change in stress upon hío resulting in hió, spelt ȝho", "ȝh = hȝ").

Note: The OE *h* is translitterated already with IPA /x/ [h], that is debatable notation suggesting a phonemic palatal which was however not realized? In an idealized Old English lect? Iotization from the *i* in OE *hio* might account for something, at least (cp. West-Frisian *hja*, North-Frisian *jü*). Problematicly PIE *yus, and *yos are not discounted, and it doesn't either account for Dutch. Maybe Dutch is intentionally not listed as cognate. However:

d) Dutch [zij] "she", "they" links *hiz, too, but also *iz.

e) Old Saxon [siu] "she", "they" likewise links *hiz, *iz, but:

- 1. There was OE nom. f. sg. [seo] "that; she, that one", which links OE "se". Weird enough, clicking the link showed me Old Saxon *se* (although the link is correctly anchored and the OE entry  does exist)

  --Eitherway, both the OE and OS entry then link *sa, suggesting PIE *so
- 2. however, Old Saxon [se] lists "siu" as its feminine form and, ironicly, [siu] traces *hiz, *iz.

This is confusing, let's take a step back.

- Old English

  > **Determiner** *sē*
  >
  > that (*masculine singular form*)
  >
  > - ***Þone*** rǣd ġerǣdde Wīdsīþ. ― Widsith gave **that** advice.
  >
  > **Pronoun** sē *m* (*demonstrative pronoun*)
  >
  > that, he (*masculine singular form*)
  >
  > ***Þā*** ne sacaþ. ― **They** do not quarrel.
  >
  > […] Middle English: se, ze, sæ
  >
  > Declension [sēo, þæt, …]
- Old Saxon

  > 1. *definite article*: the "***sē*** māno ― **the** moon"
  > 2. *demonstrative adjective:* that, those -- "*Hē gaf **thē** gift.* ― He gave **that** gift")

> Declension [se, that, siu, …]

The term *Anglo-Saxon* exists for a reason (dated when?).

**The conclusion** seems to suggest itself, that two or more different paradigms had become conflated into one by chance. But we cannot jump to the conclusion that *h spontaneously sibilified to *s* through palatization in all those languages, independently. Gothic *si* "she" as the earliest evidence  weighs rather heavy, but cannot on its own explain the plural. *si "she" also exists in Celtic, by the way. Wiktionary suggests "she" came from an independent, sporadic, phonetic development--which is doubtful.

DWDS sees the differentiation as a late development, doesn't mention *she*, and the conclusion is a logical account that however depends on the textual development accurately reflecting the oral development:

> Das Pers.pron. der **3. Person Sing**. entwickelt **in Analogie zum** einfachen Demonstrativum (Nominativ Sing. Fem. ahd. asächs. ***thiu***, Akkusativ Sing. Fem. ahd. asächs. ***thia***) einen entsprechenden femininen Nominativ ahd. asächs. ***siu*** bzw. Akkusativ ahd. asächs. ***sia***. Das dadurch mit den starken Adjektiven endungsgleiche Personalpronomen bildet **daraufhin** diesen folgende **Pluralformen** wie Nominativ und Akkusativ Mask. ahd. *sie*, asächs. *sia, sea*, Fem. ahd. *sio*, asächs. *sia, sea*, Neutr. ahd. *siu,* asächs. *siu, sia, sea.* Bereits im **Ahd**. werden die vollen Formen **vereinfacht** zu *sī, sie* und *si*, die **auch im Mhd.** gelten (mnd. *sē*, mnl. *si*), bis sich im Nhd. *sie* (nl. *zij*) an allen Stellen durchsetzt
>
> ([Wolfgang Pfeifer, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, "sie"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/sie), bold emphasis mine)

Translation of the relevant parts: *3rd p.sg. in analogy to fem.* thiu, *m.* thia *in both OHG and OE *siu, sia*; thereupon follow the pluralia; OHG simplifies these, MHG likewise (MLG, MNL).

**Misc**:

Consider just for fun whether *it car drives fast* might feel acceptable. I think it's funny because it's not acceptable--not currently anyhow. However, dialectal "them country boys", "they folks", or appellative/ *you irresponsible idiot*, referential "Why you little ...", etc. do exist. And this goes a lot further if taking *so* into account, e.g. Ger. *So sachen*, which I'd naively interpret as *su[ch] things*, "solche Dinge", whichever would be *so'ne Sachen* in my regiolect (Berlin-Brandenburg), and the singular could be seen synchronicly as contraction from *so [ei]ne Sache* (*su[ch] a thing*), but that's impossible in the plural, because no plural for the indef. art. *ein-* "a, an" exists. So, therefore, *so Sachen* it shall be. Also compare Bavarian *so'a Schmarn*. I have recently read that Bavarian "a" and English "a" are independent developments, although, those opinions have nothing to recommend themselves except the supposed distance. Bavarian is by the way far from Modern High German, but was once closer to High German-y (that is Germania Superior). Likewise, the loss of *so* as definite article is so far supposed to be have developed independently. Articles are expected to have developed relatively late from determiners and demonstratives (cf. *so, *there*, *da*). The details are not perfectly understood, because these too are found to be independent developments in the individual branches of Proto-Indo-European, so external comparison falls flat. The threepartite gender system likely followed a two-way distinction *animate-inanimate*, therefore the gloss *si "she, it" makes some sense, also that *wife* is neutre (like Old Irish *be*), or that some Hessen and Swabian dialects regularly use *das Marie*, but all that is poorly understood. Pfeifer succinctly devides both stems:

> [...] Pronominalstamm ie. *te-, *to-, der auch in allen obliquen Kasus auftritt.
>
> [besides] Nominativ Sing. Mask. und Fem. […] s- anlautenden Stamm (ie. *so m., *sā f., […]
>
> ([Wolfgang Pfeifer, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, "das [pron.]"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/das))

I had initially promissed to now derive these pronouns from first principles. At that I had hoped to rest my argument on the further reconstructions, as there are quite interesting roots. But this is impossible to achieve from the above notes alone.

PS: Save to say, *they* is described as a loan from Norse. This is comparable to Ger *die*, not *Sie*.